# How to get Steam to recognize existing game files for Arma

Tags: steam, dayz-2012, arma-2

I installed Arma Combined Operations off the anniversary disc. Now I want a new CD key to play DayZ as that one is my brothers so I purchased Arma 2 and Arma 2 Operation Arrowhead on steam.

Can I transfer the Arma files that I already have to the Steam folder so I don't have to download it? I have limited bandwidth.

I've tried to put it in steamapps under common and in the the folders that Steam makes for it when downloading. But it doesn't work it just tries to download it.

Comment: if you have the disc, maybe this will help: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39846/how-can-i-install-a-steam-game-i-bought-at-retail-from-the-disc?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to install without downloading from Steam all you need is the cd key as Arma II does not use Steam copy protection (you can run it without the steam client).

If you are referring to mods / settings:

Settings and saved missions are located in:

`Documents/ArmA 2 Other Profiles/PROFILE_NAME`

Mods are located in:

`Documents/ArmA 2/MOD_NAME`

Oh and if you need to change your cd key they are in the registry here:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Bohemia Interactive Studio`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Bohemia Interactive Studio`