# Can I install a Steam game without having to use the internet?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam, pc

So I finished building my computer and I got Steam on it by trying to install Skyrim. It gives me Steam but it says I have to have internet to continue. I'm pretty sure that I don't need online mode to install the game. I want to log in offline or just be in Steam but how do I do it? I don't have internet on my computer yet.

Answer (score 13):

You can't log into Steam in [Offline Mode](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=3160-agcb-2555) without first being online.  Step 1 of Valve's official docs for offline mode state that you should "Start Steam online."

Additionally, it's not possible to [install games without being online in Steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4293/how-can-you-install-steam-games-offline).

Further, with most Steam games [installing using the discs is a painful process](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39846/13845) as Steam tends to like to download the full game from Steam servers even if the disc is present.

Thus, even though you may have the discs for a game, if it requires Steam, you will need an internet connection in order to install it.

Comment: It is possible but we don't support piracy here.